Flutter, How to open keyboard at left side of the screen in TV application
In TV application,
When I open the keyboard, the text field is hidden below the keyboard.
I tried to add a singleChildScrollView and add padding corresponding to the keyboard height. And it is not working.
Like Here

I want to move the keyboard position at the left end of the screen

I added the code for reference.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Demo TV',
      home: LoginPageONE(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPageONE extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPageONE({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPageONE> createState() => _LoginPageONEState();
}

class _LoginPageONEState extends State<LoginPageONE> {
  TextEditingController userName = TextEditingController(text: "");
  TextEditingController pin = TextEditingController(text: "");

  FocusNode userNameFocus = FocusNode();
  FocusNode pinFocus = FocusNode();
  FocusNode loginFocus = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    userNameFocus.requestFocus();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double sHeight =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double sWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      child: PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFf5f7f9),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
            height: sHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.brown.withOpacity(0.8)),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                width: sWidth * 0.4,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                child: FocusTraversalGroup(
                  policy: OrderedTraversalPolicy(),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: sHeight * 0.08,
                              width: sWidth * 0.004,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xFFE4165C),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text("LOGIN",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    )),
                                Text(
                                    "Use your credentials to login your account.",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    )),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Text("Username",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                        child: FocusTraversalOrder(
                          order: const NumericFocusOrder(1.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: userName,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 28,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            focusNode: userNameFocus,
                            autofocus: true,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 18, right: 18, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                              filled: true,
                              isDense: true,
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                              ),
                              disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                              ),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny('  '),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Text("Password",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            )),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                        child: FocusTraversalOrder(
                          order: const NumericFocusOrder(2.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: pin,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 28,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            focusNode: pinFocus,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            scrollPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                            onSubmitted: (val) {
                              loginFocus.requestFocus();
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 18, right: 18, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              isDense: true,
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                              ),
                              disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                              ),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny('  '),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: FocusTraversalOrder(
                          order: const NumericFocusOrder(3.0),
                          child: Focus(
                            focusNode: loginFocus,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: loginFocus.hasFocus
                                    ? const Color(0xFF303188)
                                    : const Color(0xFFE4165C),
                                minimumSize: Size(sWidth * 0.4, sHeight * 0.07),
                                maximumSize: Size(sWidth * 0.4, sHeight * 0.07),
                                shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: const Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Login",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            onKeyEvent: (_, event) {
                              if (event.logicalKey ==
                                  LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowUp) {
                                userNameFocus.requestFocus();
                                setState(() {});
                                return KeyEventResult.handled;
                              }
                              if (event.logicalKey ==
                                  LogicalKeyboardKey.select) {
                                debugPrint("BTN Clicked");
                              }
                              return KeyEventResult.ignored;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

